# Displaying line bellow TouchableOpacity options wrapped in a View at the border of parent

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I have a menu like component in React Native, which is wrapped in a View. This View has 3 options. I would like each option to have a line below it almost touching border of the view.

In order to achieve this I have three TouchableOpacities with Text and a View, all wrap under the same parent. This is what my code looks like:

```
export function Menu () {
  return (
    <View style={{
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      backgroundColor: 'grey',
      height: 50,
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
      alignContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center'
    }}>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>Option 1</Text>
        <View
          style={{
            width: 50,
            height: 4,
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            paddingTop: 0,
            marginTop: 25,
            marginBottom: 0
          }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity> <Text>Option 2</Text> </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity> <Text>Option 3</Text> </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

The issue here is that by placing the inner View at the bottom through `marginTop: 25`, I push my text to the top of their parent, which I do not want. Here is the result of this code:

[image]

See how Option 2 and Option 3 are centered within their parent? That is exactly how I want Option 1 to be, but with the red line right on the edge of the grey box wrapping all three options.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Give the `<Text />` above red line `<View>` a style of `flex:1` and remove `marginTop: 25` from `<View>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap the `<Text>` inside a a `<View>`. Its been quite some time since I last worked on RN but I think this code should give you the desired result.

```
<TouchableOpacity>
  <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', height: 46}}><Text>Option 1</Text></View>
  <View
      style={{
        width: 50,
        height: 4,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        paddingTop: 0,
        marginTop: 25,
        marginBottom: 0
      }}
    />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

PS: I think it should work even without the `height: 46` for the `<View>` but I can't test it at the moment so can't assure.

Comment: Perfect! Did not need to wrap the Text in View, but otherwise that did the trick! Thanks!